# import/open/read quantumworldX-0.18.44.tar.gz on python

Tags: python, import

I want to open/import a file, which i downloaded from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/quantumworldX), with python. It is a library with formulas. I'm thinking something like you import math. 
I'm running python 3.6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading found at https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html

With the quantumworldX installed, unzip the tar file. Next, open up a terminal/command prompt in the extracted folder. Or you can open a terminal and use the cd command to change directories to the extracted folder.

After your terminal is in the folder, run the command:

```
python setup.py install
```

This will install quantumworldX as a module in python. However, before you are ready to import the module, you must have the required modules installed as well.

The listed modules comes in the folder /quantumworldX.egg-info under "requires".
They include: Numpy, Scipy, Matplotlib and Cycler. To install these modules, go back into your terminal and use pip as follows:

```
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
pip install matplotlib
pip install cycler
```

Each after the other finishes. After you have setup.py installed and the prerequisites, you can test if you have it properly installed by running

```
import quantumworldX as qwx
```

in an IDLE. If you get no error, you have properly installed quantumworldX and may use it accordingly.